# Can't resolve all parameters for xyz: (?, ?) since Angular2 CLI Upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript

I upgraded my Angular2 project which was working fine from Beta .21 to beta .25.5. I have fixed all error so that there are no errors when using AOT or non-AOT (e.g. ng serve)

I now get this error on many of my services at runtime when the browser loads and it affects ALL the parameter services for that file.

```
Can't resolve all parameters for *servicename*: (?)
```

First I deleted the barrel I was using and checked circular dependancies.

I then moved them all into the Providers array in App.module and checked that all services have @Injectable().
the only way to get rid of the error was to use the Inject() method, eg:

```
import { Injectable, Optional, SkipSelf, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

export interface SpinnerState {
    show: boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
    private spinnerSubject = new Subject<SpinnerState>();

    spinnerState = this.spinnerSubject.asObservable();

    constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() @Inject(SpinnerService) prior: SpinnerService) {
```

This fixed the errors but then I got this error on a 3rd party library. How can I debug this to work out the root cause of the problem?

Thanks

"`nativeError : Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Logger: (?). at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:134335:27) [<r`"

This is how my App.Module looks:

```
 providers: [
        {
            provide: AuthHttp,
            useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
            deps: [Http, RequestOptions],
        },
        [Logger],
        LoggerService,
        SpinnerService,
        DataBreezeService,
        ProfileService,
        AuthService,
        AuthGuardService,
        CanDeactivateGuardService,
```

I also have these set:

```
{
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true
}
```

(as mentioned, my project was working fine before the upgrade - I can't see anything obvious in the release notes).

**UPDATE**
I kept commenting out services with issues and removing params from constructors and each time it just moves to the next service - ie. there is something wrong at a higher level here. Now I am also getting 404 errors on components too, eg.

[image]

I don't understand why - for example, the 404 Subscribe component is really simple:  I even tried adding "moduleId: 'module.id', "  but that made no difference:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-subscribe',
    templateUrl: './subscribe.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./subscribe.component.scss']
})
export class SubscribeComponent {

    constructor() { }
}
```

GET http://localhost:4200/subscribe.component.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: How does the constructor for `Logger` look like?

Comment: Why did you wrap `Logger` with an array `[Logger],`? - should work fine, just curious

Comment: WRT the last question - that was just an oversight - I changed that.

Comment: WRT the Logger library - I just commented it out completely - now it moves to the next class with the same error - ie. there is something really wrong here at a higher level - it is not a particular class or service error I don't think.

Comment: I think it's just a circular dependency, probably on `Http` and Angular DI uses constructor injection where circular dependencies can't be supported.

Comment: Ok, I will go through and keep commenting out all dependencies to try and find a circular one - is there an easier way to debug it perhaps? I also added more information - now I am getting 404 errors on many components (these were all working fine in the previous CLI version)

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way. You can start with commenting out only `Http` because it's quite likely the culprit.

Comment: Ok, I managed to sort this out (12 hours later). I still don't know what caused it, but all the above was a red-herring - I rolled back all my changes in the end. I pinned some exact versions of Angular and other libraries in my packages.json and deleted the node folder and reinstalled. It then seemed to work... very frustrating but at least it is now working in AOT... thanks for the help

Comment: Which specific changes you did? I am struck at same stage as you were.

Answer (score 0):

got it up and running by **removing all barrel imports** and going up to beta 28.3

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3
```

and also update to 28.3 locally in project folder (update angular-cli.json & package.json).

Comment: Out of interest, why did you not upgrade to RC1? There's a lot of good stuff in the later releases

Comment: yes definitely, i replied just in case somebody needs a fix urgently :)